# Adding words from string to list c#

Tags: c#, list

I am having trouble adding words from a string to my list.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

string StringSorter = "Hello I like C#";

            for (int i = 0; i < StringSorter.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] splitter = StringSorter.Split(" ");
                list.Add(splitter[i]);
            }
```

I want every word to be in an index in the list. And it works until the end of the string is reached where it crashes and it says "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I simply can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: First, split your string into an array, then loop and add items to your list.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `List<string> list = StringSorter.Split(" ").ToList();`? (You only want to split once, not once for each character in the string.)

Comment: `StringSorter.Length` is the number of *characters* in `StringSorter`, which is 15. `splitter` contains the *words* in `StringSorter`, i.e. the strings `Hello`, `I`, `like`, `C#`, of which there are 4. You're trying to use `i`, which goes from 0 to 14 (inclusive), to index into `splitter`, which only contains 4 elements. It should be obvious why this will try to access elements 4-14, and fail

Comment: You rptroblem is, that you try to split the string "StringSorter" for every character that is in your string. But you have to do this only once.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I saw my mistake. I was looping and splitting for every character instead of every word, causing it to go out of bounds!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you iterate over each character inside your string and try to split the string for each iteration.

You only have to split your string once.

You could do it like this:

```
string myString = "Hello I like C#";
List<string> list = new List<string>();

string[] splittedStringArray = myString.Split(' ');

foreach (string stringInArray in splittedStringArray) {
    list.Add(stringInArray);
}
```

As already mentioned in the comments you could use the linq extension method **ToList()** to cast the returning array of your Split Function directly to a List like this:

```
string myString = "Hello I like C#";

List<string> list = myString.Split(' ').ToList();
```

One more thing you can do is to use the **AddRange()** function of your list. So you have no need to cast your returning array to a list. This will also make it easier if you want to do this many times:

```
string myStringOne = "Hello I like C#";
string myStringTwo = "I copied the top comment for my answere";

List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.AddRange(myStringOne.Split(' '));
list.AddRange(myStringTwo.Split(' '));
```